# Trying to check a specific checkbox when the textbox matches the ID number of a model in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I have the following three tables:

`Student`, `Register` and a join table called `Student_Register`.
[image]

To make it easier to understand, here is the model for each:

```
class Register < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :student_registers
  has_many :students, :through => :student_registers
  belongs_to :event
  attr_accessible :date, :student_ids, :module_class_id, :event_id
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :student_registers
  has_many :registers, :through => :student_registers
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :university_id
end

class StudentRegister < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :register
  belongs_to :student
  attr_accessible :present, :register_id, :student_id, :time_of_arrival
  default_scope :order => 'present DESC'
end
```

So now what I want to do, is using the `Register`controller to open a certain Register and to mark that register on the `register/1/registration` page. That works fine. However what I have at the moment is the following:
[image]
Each checkbox has a submit button attached to it, however I hid it using `:style => 'display: none'`. The following code might give you a better image of what is going on:

**`register/registration.html.erb`**

```
<table border="1">
  <%= text_field_tag 'Card_ID',nil,  :autofocus => true %>
      <tr><td>Present</td>
        <td>University ID</td>
    <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Time of Arrival</td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
  <% @studentregister.each do |t| %>
<%= simple_form_for t do |streg| %>
      <td><div class="present"><%= streg.check_box :present, :onChange => "submit()"%>  </div>
        <%= streg.submit :style => 'display: none' %></td>
            <td><%= streg.label Student.find(t.student_id).university_id %></td>
            <td><%= streg.label Student.find(t.student_id).first_name %></td>
            <td><%= streg.label Student.find(t.student_id).last_name %></td>
            <% if t.time_of_arrival %>
            <td><%= streg.label t.time_of_arrival.strftime('%H:%M:%S%P')%></td>
                <% else %>
            <td><%= streg.label " "%></td>
                <% end %>
             </tr>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

The source of that page looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is the following:

When the text that is put in the textbox matches one of the `University ID` of a student, I want the corresponding checkbox to checked, and in theory, once it gets checked, the form for it gets automatically submitted and 'hey presto', the form for it gets updated.

This is my current JS/Coffeescript code:

**`registers.js.coffee`**

```
$("input[name=Card_ID]").keyup ->
  if @value.length > 3
    $("input[name=\"student_register[present]\"]").prop "checked", true
  else
    $("input[name=\"student_register[present]\"]").prop "checked", false
```

I know this code doesn't do what I want it to do, mainly because my JS/Coffeescript knowledge is 0, but also because I just wanted to check if it works that when the textbox has values of length greater than 3 it should check one/all checkboxes (not sure what this code would check, as the  is not very clear and the  for the checkboxes is the same), however it doesn't work.

I don't even know how I can use Ruby code to search for the `University ID` and match it with a student. I'm literally confused at the moment, been at this for three days now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to get your question surfing around the jumbo size description O_O. If I got it right you want something like this:

The form has an `id` attribute, use it. Take a look at your HTML's structure:

```
# Each 'student_register' form has an id "edit_student_register_#{id}"
# where id is the object's id
# Inside each of these forms there is a check box with name "student_register[present]"

<form id="edit_student_register_15">
  <input name="student_register[present]"/>
</form>

# So you need to get that input with a selector like this:
$("input[name=Card_ID]").keyup (e)->
  if e.wich is 13 # If enter key is pressed...
    id = this.text # To interpolate in the selector below
    $("form#student_register_#{id} input[name='student_register[present]']").attr 'checked', true
```

Play around in the browsers console to check what your selectors are bringing up.

Comment: sorry for the jumbo sized description (-_-'), just wanted to make sure that I don't leave out anything. So when you say add a `content_tag`, would that be after the `<%= simple_form_for t do |streg| %>`?

Comment: Yep, it generates a `<td>` tag with the block you pass to it as it's contetents. I strongly suggest you to stop 10 mins and try to switch to [HAML](http://haml.info/). It's gonna make your life a lot easier.

Comment: I done the changes but nothing has changed, still not working. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, what should I write in the text_box?

Comment: had a bit of a play around, still nothing ... do you want me to put the code up on GitHub for you to check it out yourself?